# Organizing large number of profiles in jboss domain configuration

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a jboss domain server with 10-20 profiles.

Basically I have 10-20 instances of the same application running on different ports.

The settings on the profiles are 90% identical, the only difference being datasource and logging configurations.

I'm copy/pasting one profile for each application instance, so my **domain.xml** is quickly getting bigger and bigger, and most of the settings are duplicated.

If I could do one of the following two things, it would help me make the maintenance of much easier:

1. Is there a way to reuse a profile and pass parameters from the server-groups in order to change a little bit of configuration.

Example:

```
    <server-group name="instance1-group" profile="common_template-ha">
          <!-- This are the bits and pieces that are different between instances  -->
          <datasource>
               .... configuration
          </datasource>
          <logging>
               .... configuration
          </logging>
    </server-group>
```

2. Can I split the **domain.xml** file in several different small files, each one containing a single profile configuration?

Example:

```
<profiles>
    <!-- profiles would be imported from 3 other files -->
    <profile source="profile-instance1.xml />
    <profile source="profile-instance2.xml />
    <profile source="profile-instance3.xml />
</profiles>
```